# Refresh tableview after delete a tableview cell and refresh view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, refresh

I need answer for swift by the way. Basically, I have two questions for refreshing. If you think the code is too long to look at, this is what I'm trying to do. one is to refresh the tableview after clicking on the delete button on one of the tableview cell. I've tried refreshcontrol, it didn't work and it wasn't what I wanted but it would be cool to have them. My other question is, how to refresh a view controller by clicking on of the buttons. And here is the code.

The delete button is inside of my custom cell class
class postCell: UITableViewCell{

```
@IBOutlet weak var deleteBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var postImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var category: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var location: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
var prices = String()
var notes = String()
var comments = String()
var locations = String()
var categories = String()
var school = String()
var username = String()
var date = String()


@IBAction func deleteAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.percyteng.com/orbit/deletePost.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "name=\(username)&location=\(locations)&price=\(prices)&notes=\(notes)&school=\(school)&category=\(categories)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume();           NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifie‌​r", object: nil)


}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated:animated)
}
}
```

And the tableview i want to reload data of in another class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    username = tempUser.username
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller

    })()
    get{(value) in
        self.values = value
        for ele in self.values{
            if self.username != ele["username"] as! String{
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(serviceBoard.methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent), name:"NotificationIdentifie‌​r", object: nil)

}

func methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent(){
    tableView.reloadData()
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (self.resultSearchController.active && resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        return self.filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {
        return values.count
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!postCell
    let maindata = values[values.count-1-indexPath.row]

    if (self.resultSearchController.active && resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "") {


        //            if (filteredTableData[indexPath.row].rangeOfString("###") == nil){
        cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named:"tile_services")
        cell.title.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.category.text = "SERVICES"
        var price = String()
        for i in values{
            if (i["title"] as? String)! == filteredTableData[indexPath.row]{
                price = (i["price"] as? String)!
                cell.categories = "Services"
                cell.username = i["username"] as! String
                cell.prices = i["price"] as! String
                cell.notes = i["notes"] as! String
                cell.school = i["school"] as! String
            }
        }
        cell.price.text = price 

        return cell
    }
    else {
        if maindata["username"] as! String != username && username != "admin"{
            cell.deleteBtn.hidden = true
        }
        else{
            cell.categories = "Services"
            cell.username = maindata["username"] as! String
            cell.prices = maindata["price"] as! String
            cell.notes = maindata["notes"] as! String
            cell.school = maindata["school"] as! String
        }

        cell.postImg.image = UIImage(named:"tile_services")
        cell.title.text = maindata["title"] as? String
        cell.category.text = "SERVICES"
        cell.price.text = maindata["price"] as? String

        return cell
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showPostT") as! showPostT
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    if (self.resultSearchController.active && resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "") {
        for i in values{
            if (i["title"] as? String)! == filteredTableData[indexPath.row]{
                popOverVC.type.text = "SERVICE"
                popOverVC.typeImg.image = UIImage(named:"tile_services")
                popOverVC.item.text = "Service: \(i["title"] as! String)"
                popOverVC.price.text = "Price: \(i["price"] as! String)"
                popOverVC.notes.text = "Notes: \(i["notes"] as! String)"
                popOverVC.comments.text = i["comments"] as? String
                popOverVC.postUser.text = i["username"] as! String
                popOverVC.notesStr = i["notes"] as! String
                popOverVC.category = "service"
                popOverVC.pricesStr = i["price"] as! String
                if username == popOverVC.postUser.text!{
                    popOverVC.composeBtn.hidden = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        let maindata = values[values.count-1-indexPath.row]
        popOverVC.type.text = "SERVICE"
        popOverVC.typeImg.image = UIImage(named:"tile_services")
        popOverVC.item.text = "Service: \(maindata["title"] as! String)"
        popOverVC.price.text = "Price: \(maindata["price"] as! String)"
        popOverVC.notes.text = "Notes: \(maindata["notes"] as! String)"
        popOverVC.comments.text = maindata["comments"] as? String
        popOverVC.postUser.text = maindata["username"] as! String
        popOverVC.notesStr = maindata["notes"] as! String
        popOverVC.category = "service"
        popOverVC.pricesStr = maindata["price"] as! String

        if username == popOverVC.postUser.text!{
            popOverVC.composeBtn.hidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

I don't think I need code for my second question, I simply want to know how to refresh a view controller. I tried to close the current controller and reopen it, but it obviously doesn't work.

I would really appreciate if you guys can help any of the questions!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , First of all, if you want to refresh the tableview data you must notify it, so it knows if there are any changes in the model.
If you want to reload the whole table view (I strongly advised not to do it)
you can use

```
 tableView.reloadData()
```

If you want to refresh certain rows use the following methods:

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(paths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

Or you could use this method only for delete action. Observe the tap on button event and send signal to the tableView to delete the row. When the tableView receive this signal, just pass execute the following method.

```
 tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

forcing redraw of your custom view :  `view.setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: The problem is that my delete button action is in my custom cell, how would I be able to refer the tableview within that action? The tableview is not defined in the custom cell

Comment: I suggest you get familiar with some of the following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern  , NSNotificationCenter, KeyValue observing or ReactivePrograming ( Reactive Kit)  https://github.com/ReactiveKit/ReactiveKit

Comment: So do you mean I send a signal to notification center when I click the delete button in the custom cell to notify the subject which is the tableview that contains the custom cell? Do you mind sharing the notification code? Thx

Comment: Yeah sure not problem.  I personally use reactive programing and binding for that, but that might be to much of a bite for you. Now first on action handler you post the notification like that :     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil). Then observe it on  viewDidLoad with:        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent(_:)), name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
       And implement your "methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent()"

Comment: Just want to make sure that when you say viewDidLoad, you mean the viewDidLoad in the class that contains the tableview not the custom cell class, right? And the "methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent()" is the name of a method that I write corresponding reaction to the notification in the class that contains the tableview right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you have resolved the problem, please accept the answer and let's close the question.

Comment: Yea, I will test it out when I get home and if it works I will definitely accept your answer! But I have two questions so I can't close it until I get the second one but I think it should be easy for you to resolve. I just want to know how to refresh a view controller when I click on a button.

Comment: So I did     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(serviceBoard.methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent), name:"NotificationIdentifie‌​r", object: nil)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent(){
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
And I have tested that when I click delete button, it goes into methodhandlingTheNotificationEvent(), but it just doesn't reload tableview. I also have post notification from my custom cell. Where went wrong?

Comment: I just realized I posted the wrong code and I updated my code, wanna take a look?

Comment: You should post the notification, as I mentioned, in the cell's method @IBAction func deleteAction(sender: AnyObject)

Comment: I did that also and I have made sure that it actually goes in the methodhandlingnotification method

Comment: Should I load the updated data from database before I reload my database?

Comment: Yes you are responsible for keeping the integrity between model and the view. Update your model, and then notify the view to update itself.(the simplest MVC solution)

Answer (score 0):

Reload tableview data

[_tableView reloadData];

Comment: I have tried that when I click on a refresh button and that did nothing