# tableview doesn't refresh deleted data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My table view does not refresh. it keep the old values of deleted data
and can show new added values.
it only refresh(remove deleted values) when i close the app and open it again.

here is my code

```
private func observeChannels() {
let userEmail = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
channelRefHandle = channelRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  let channelData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    let id = snapshot.key
    let groupimage = channelData["groupImage"] as? String!
    let descc = channelData["desc"] as? String!
    let groupCountvar = channelData["Members"]?.count
    let groupTasksVar = channelData["Tasks"]?.count

   if let name = channelData["name"] as! String!, name.characters.count > 0 {
    //members snapshot
    if let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Members") as? DataSnapshot{
        if let membersDictionary = childSnapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] , membersDictionary.count > 0{
            for membersDictionary in membersDictionary {
                if userEmail == membersDictionary.value as? String {
                    self.groups.append(Group(id: id,name: name, createdBy: (userEmail)!, desc: (descc)!, groupImage: (groupimage)!, groupCount: ("\(groupCountvar!)") , groupTasksCount: ("\(groupCountvar!)")))
                    print(membersDictionary.value)

                }
      }
    }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }}else {
    print("Error!")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
})}
```

datasource / delegate

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 2 }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if let currentSection: Section = Section(rawValue: section) {
  switch currentSection {
  case .createNewChannelSection:
    return 0
  case .currentChannelsSection:
    return groups.count
  }
} else {
  return 0 }
 }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 75.0 }

 //tableView
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExistingChannel", for: indexPath) as! GroupTableViewCell
if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.currentChannelsSection.rawValue {
        cell.goupName?.text = groups[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].name
        cell.groupDesc?.text = groups[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].desc
        cell.groupimg?.image = UIImage(named: groups[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].groupImage)
        cell.numbMembLbl?.text = groups[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].groupCount
    cell.taskNumbLbl?.text = groups[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].groupTasksCount

}


return cell }

// MARK: UITableViewDelegate

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == Section.currentChannelsSection.rawValue {
  let channel = groups[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChannel", sender: channel)
} }
```

this is my table view i dont know why the deleted/removed doesn't observe.

Comment: Please share tableview delegate and datasource

Comment: @kamel call reloading on main thread, all UI related task should be done on main thread.

Comment: its difficult to answer your question unless you share delegate methods..

Comment: @RahulDasgupta i just did.

Comment: @YashBedi i just did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh tableview after delete a tableview cell and refresh view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436485/refresh-tableview-after-delete-a-tableview-cell-and-refresh-view-controller)

Comment: you are maintaining data in your array self.groups , can you debug what values after you refreshing your array ? i am sure your array containing same values. if it contain same values before refreshing remove all values from array and then add data in it. @Kamel

Answer (score 1):

You are observing the node for .childChanged events only.

That means the code in the closure will only fire if a child is changed.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

> FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged - Listen for changes to the items in a
>   list. This event is triggered any time a child node is modified. This
>   includes any modifications to descendants of the child node. The
>   snapshot passed to the event listener contains the updated data for
>   the child.

So that means the code in your closure will only be called when a child is changed, and will *not* be called when a child is added or deleted.

You need to add additional observers for .childAdded events and .childRemoved events to handle those cases. When you receive a childAdded event, add that snapshot data to your array and likewise when you receive a childRemoved event, remove it from the array.

Remember to reload your table view in all cases so the UI updates with the fresh data.

I personally would change this line to make it more readable

```
for membersDictionary in membersDictionary {
```

to

```
for member in membersDictionary {
```

but that's just a style thing.

Comment: A downvote for the correct answer with an explanation. Hmmm.

Comment: If you plan on voting either up or down for this answer, *please* take a moment and review the code in the question; the OP is *only* observing childChanged events so the app will never be notified of items that are added or removed which is causing the dataSource array go stale.

Comment: i solved the issue by using .value instead of childcChanged. Thank you all for helping me solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for reloading `tableView`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This will help.

Comment: lol. No, that won't help at all and has nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
 UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .delete {
  print("Deleted")
  self.yourArrayName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
  self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
 }
}
```

It'll do the job.